# R dataframe subset collation optimization

Tags: r

This isn't a question about how to do something per se, it's more about how to do something better.

In R, say I have a dataframe, df:

```
df<-read.table(text="
Column1  Column2   Category    
   1        1         A   
   2        1         B       
   3        1         D       
   4        1         E       
   5        2         B       
   6        3         B       
   7        4         C
   8        4         C       
   9        5         E       
   10       6         A", header=TRUE)
```

Now I would like to create a list (of dataframes) where each dataframe in the list is a subset of df where each subset is conditional on Category. I can create this as follows:

```
mylist <-list()
mylist[[1]] <- subset(df,df$Category=='A')
mylist[[2]] <- subset(df,df$Category=='B')
mylist[[3]] <- subset(df,df$Category=='C')
mylist[[4]] <- subset(df,df$Category=='D')
mylist[[5]] <- subset(df,df$Category=='E')
```

Now this works but is pretty clunky, is effectively a hard-coded loop and won't scale easily if I have more than five categories.

Is there a tighter/better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function split

```
split(df,df$Category)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr library and loop for this case:

```
library(dplyr)
mylist <-list()
for ( v in unique(df$Category)){
  mylist[[length(mylist)+1]] <- filter(df, Category == v)
}
mylist
```

Comment: If you were operating with `dplyr` you'd probably just do `df %>% group_by(Category)` and then apply whatever calculations you need to those subsets with another `%>%`. The package explicitly tries to avoid using `list` objects in favour of `data.frame` like objects.